# Map returns empty even though its being filled

Tags: javascript

I have an object , where i am iterating over key values and trying to fill in map , but my map returns empty ?

i have tried using map.set and map[key] = value but none fills it

```js
let object1 = {"ItemType":"Star","values":{"a0k2E0000018AcbQAE":"3","a0k2E0000018AcWQAU":"2","a0k2E0000018AcgQAE":"4","a0k2E0000018AclQAE":"5","a0k2E0000018AcDQAU":"1"}};
//console.log(Object.keys(object1));
let ab = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(key, value);
  if(key === 'Itemtype') {
    
    ab.set(key,value);
  }
}

console.log('new thing ' + JSON.stringify(ab));
```

new thing {}

Comment: `JSON.stringify(new Map([[1,1],[2,2]]))` => `"{}"`

Comment: `"Itemtype" !== "ItemType"` - it's case sensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think, it because your condition is fail, it has to be like this:

```
  if(key === 'ItemType') { // you have Itemtype, it does not exist

    ab.set(key,value);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.stringify(ab)` will treat `ab` as a simple object; it doesn't know anything about Map instances. In general, because Map keys can be arbitrary objects, JSON is not going to be able to represent quite a lot of working Map structures.

You could possibly do something like `JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()))` but it won't work in many cases.

Alternatively, if you know your keys are always strings, you could just use a plain object instead of a Map.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemType` is typed as `Itemtype`

```js
let object1 = {"ItemType":"Star","values":{"a0k2E0000018AcbQAE":"3","a0k2E0000018AcWQAU":"2","a0k2E0000018AcgQAE":"4","a0k2E0000018AclQAE":"5","a0k2E0000018AcDQAU":"1"}};
//console.log(Object.keys(object1));
let ab = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
    console.log(key, value);
  if(key === 'ItemType') {
    
    ab[key]=value;
  }
}

console.log('new thing ' + JSON.stringify(ab));
```